# how to trace stl src code, for example std::string , with IDE(vscode)?

Tags: c++, string, debugging, stl, vscode-debugger

I am a c++ beginer；Here is my issue;
I want to track down the implementation of some containers in stl, such as constructors, copy control members, and so on; to See how it is implemented;
I copy a sample code from cplusplus about std::string constructor as below, and then using vscode to debug , when progarm run the definition of s1,s2,s3,s4,s5.. , I can't step into to the std::string Constructor src code,
What do I need to do to step into  the source code of stl? thanks!

```
//string constructor
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s0("Initial string");

    // constructors used in the same order as described above :
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2(s0);
    std::string s3(s0, 8, 3);
    std::string s4("A character sequence");
    std::string s5("Another character sequence", 12);
    std::string s6a(10, 'x');
    std::string s6b(10, 42);      // 42 is the ASCII code for '*'
    std::string s7(s0.begin(), s0.begin() + 7);

    std::cout << "s1: " << s1 << "\ns2: " << s2 << "\ns3: " << s3;
    std::cout << "\ns4: " << s4 << "\ns5: " << s5 << "\ns6a: " << s6a;
    std::cout << "\ns6b: " << s6b << "\ns7: " << s7 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

try in vscode, but can't step into the src code;

Comment: what compiler? what debugger? what compile flags?

Comment: I just find the corresponding constructor in e.g. <string> and add a breakpoint... It's easier for other functions, you can use e.g. "peek definition" to get the position of it.